# Route with nullable parameters showing up with query string for null route value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller action:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ActionResult Bar(int? barId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The corresponding route for this action is given by:

```
routes.MapRoute("Foobar", "bar/{barId}",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar", barId = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { barId = @"^[0-9]+$" });
```

In my views, I'm generating routes as:

```
@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo", new { barId = bar.BarId })
```

For `bar.BarId = 32`, I receive the expected URL of `/Foo/32`

But I would also like to generate routes for `null` values as:

```
@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo", new { barId = (int?)null })
```

Except, for this I receive the URL of `/Foo?barId=currentBarId`

Where `currentBarId` is the `barId` of whatever `Bar` page I'm currently viewing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constraint on:

```
new { barId = @"^[0-9]*$" }
```

this will allow empty `barId` for this route.

Comment: it doesn't works with `@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo")`, but with `@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo", new { barId = (int?)null })` it actualy does. Have update unswer accordingly